# Automatically move uploaded file on Azure

Tags: php, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I have a video file, which i'm uploading with php as blob to Windows Azure. Is there some way to make Azure move this file in media storage, re-encode it and publish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow c# example in Azure Media Services GItHub repository . https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/tree/master/samples/CopyBlobsIntoAnAsset.

Once asset in your storage account (which is associated with media service) has been created, you can create a required job to encode asset,then publish output asset so it can be streamed or downloaded.
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/media-services/how-to-guides/deliver-streaming-content/